# Как отредактировать код GTA V

Tags: разработка-игр

Здравствуйте 
Возможно ли редактировать код ГТА 5, интересует именно редактирование навигатора
Handling meta, это как я понял только для авто

Answer (score 7):

Код `GTA 5` не находится в открытом доступе, поэтому редактировать его будет затруднительно, но такое возможно.

Для этого нужно нужно выучить [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), английский язык и отправить резюме на вакансию разработчика [Gameplay Programmer](https://www.rockstargames.com/careers/openings/position/4375b8a9):

> QUALIFICATIONS
>
> - A degree in computer science, mathematics, or equivalent.
> - Minimum of 2 years commercial games programming experience with at least one shipped game title; preferably on the Xbox and/or
>   Playstation consoles.
> - Prior experience working with camera, animations, AI, or game physics is ideal.
>
> SKILLS
>
> - Solid C/C++ programming skills.
> - Strong math skills, knowledge of vectors, matrices and linear algebra.
> - Excellent problem solving ability.
> - Good team communication skills.
> - Strong OO design understanding.
> - Passion for playing and creating cutting edge video game experiences.

Comment: остроумный ответ!  :-)